# What is the time complexity when dividing by 2 until reaching 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

```
i=100
while i>=1:
  i=i//2
  print(i)
```

What is the time complexity in upper bound for the following code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: Thank you I will keep it in mind. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `i = 100`, i is a constant and hence the time complexity is `O(1)`.

If i is a variable that changes based on the input, then the time complexity is `O(log i)` as you keep dividing i by 2.

`print(i)` is executed `log i` times, hence it does not change the final time complexity.

Comment: What is `n`? Did you mean `O(log i)`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `O(log i)`. @Stef

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `i` can change or vary this is a `O(log n)` logarithmic complexity. (Otherwise, it would be constant time)

The number of loops is logarithmically proportional to the size of `i`.

See how it scales:

```
i size  -> # of loops  
10      -> 4
100     -> 7
1000    -> 10
10000   -> 14
100000  -> 17
```

---

For reference see how different complexities scale in time:

(extracted from https://medium.com/better-programming/a-gentle-explanation-of-logarithmic-time-complexity-79842728a702) :
[image]